Connecting to MQTT server problem solving
I have ESP8266 project in Arduino IDE that connects to AWS MQTT server. For this purpose PubSubClient (https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/) library was used.
After connect procedure execution I get crash.
Function:
pubsubClient.connect(config.mqtt.id, config.mqtt.username, config.mqtt.password))

Crash:
:ref 1

_iobuf_in:       0x3fff5ebc
_iobuf_out:      0x3fff3f94
_iobuf_in_size:  16709
_iobuf_out_size: 597
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
Exception (28):
epc1=0x4021f88f epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00003a98 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3fff0bc0 end: 3fff0fd0 offset: 0150
3fff0d10:  00000000 2c9f0300 4000050c 3fffc278  
3fff0d20:  00000000 00000000 00000022 40234a30  
...

I was trying to enable debugging by setting highest log level:

But no additional information was captured on debug serial.
How to find crash problem in my project?
Exception decoder brings:
Exception 9: LoadStoreAlignmentCause: Load or store to an unaligned address
PC: 0x4024232d: br_x509_minimal_run at src/x509\x509_minimal.c:1203
EXCVADDR: 0x0000252d

Decoding stack results
0x4023cdb4: br_ssl_hs_client_run at src/ssl\ssl_hs_client.c:1877
0x4023af50: jump_handshake at src\inner.h:2211
0x4023b33d: br_ssl_engine_sendrec_ack at src/ssl\ssl_engine.c:1168
0x4021552e:  is in BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::_run_until(unsigned int, bool) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:586).
0x4023af50: jump_handshake at src\inner.h:2211
0x4023c0a8: br_ssl_hs_client_run at src/ssl\ssl_hs_client.c:960
0x40215588: BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::_wait_for_handshake() at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:609
0x4021585b:  is in BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::_connectSSL(char const*) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:1194).
0x40101218: umm_malloc(size_t) at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.cpp:912
0x402354e8: ip4_output_if_opt at core/ipv4\ip4.c:1572
0x4022cd75: mem_malloc at core\mem.c:210
0x4023550e: ip4_output_if at core/ipv4\ip4.c:1549
0x40236467: ip_chksum_pseudo at core\inet_chksum.c:392
0x4021d70c: __esp_suspend() at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_features.h:64
0x4021d85d:  is in __esp_delay(unsigned long) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp:161).
0x4021d8d2:  is in esp_try_delay(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp:182).
0x4021d8d2:  is in esp_try_delay(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp:182).
0x40214306:  is in WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, unsigned short) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266/coredecls.h:69).
0x402354b2: ip4_output_if_src at core/ipv4\ip4.c:1589
0x4021593b:  is in BearSSL::WiFiClientSecureCtx::connect(char const*, unsigned short) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp:228).
0x40218a84:  is in PubSubClient::connect(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned char, bool, char const*, bool) (c:\ArduinoTest\libraries\PubSubClient\src\PubSubClient.cpp:196).
0x40231bd8: udp_sendto_if at core\udp.c:692
0x4021d7ba: __yield() at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_features.h:64
0x40218c6c:  is in PubSubClient::connect(char const*, char const*, char const*) (c:\ArduinoTest\libraries\PubSubClient\src\PubSubClient.cpp:170).
0x40206ef1:  is in sendMQTT(unsigned long, String, String) (C:\ArduinoTest\vtsistema/vtsistema.ino:172).
0x4021c375:  is in String::copy(char const*, unsigned int) (C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\WString.cpp:274).
0x402084ff: loop() at C:\ArduinoTest\vtsistema\vtsistema.ino:599
0x402177c0: fs::FS::_defaultTimeCB() at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\FS.h:260
0x401011d6: umm_free(void*) at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.cpp:688
0x402177c0: fs::FS::_defaultTimeCB() at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\FS.h:260
0x4021d944: loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp:258


Have you fed the crash report into the exception decoder?

@hardillb I have added decoded stack result in question body.  But how to find problem in that?

Well it's failing here. That line is referencing trust anchors so it's probable that the issue is related to whatever you are passing to setTrustAnchor (without an example it's difficult to comment further).
